# Programatically find page load times for top-1000 websites

Tags: firefox, browser, time

I have a list of the top 1000 websites. I want to access each website in a browser (render all images, execute all javascript, etc.) and log the load time.

Any suggestions as to the best way of doing this?

I thought about using a headless browser, but not sure if this is the best way.

I know Firebug has load times, but I have 1,000 websites and this process would be very tedious. Also, I have a couple of parameters to tweak so need to go through the 1,000 websites a couple of times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were doing this I'd write a short perl script using WWW::Mechanize::Firefox module to request the pages, logging the page load times to a file.

[http://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize::Firefox](http://metacpan.org/pod/WWW%3a%3aMechanize%3a%3aFirefox)

Comment: Great! Never came across that one. I even searched CPAN! I'd much prefer to use Perl than use HtmlUnit (in Java).

Comment: Everything's working now. Only took me about 30 minutes to get script up-and-running...

Comment: @Raoul - Can you share the script, if that is not too much to ask for while I go through the link in your answer ?