# Java Runtime exec: Get information from Firefox

Tags: java, firefox, exec, runtime.exec

With Java I am able to open Firefox just fine with a URL I set using this code:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe" + " " + "http://www.website.com");
```

But if possible how can I then return the following data?

1. If Firefox loaded successfully? (As a bool)
2. If the URL(s) loaded successfully? (As a bool, or if using more than 1 URL as a bool array)
3. The time taken to load (As a value/string, or if using more than 1 URL as a value/string array.
4. The contents of the Firefox Web Console (As a string, or if using more than 1 URL as a string array)

Is there a way to do this and get back this type of data from Firefox or other programs that .exec is launching?

Comment: Don't do that.  You cannot assume that your users have Firefox, or that they even have a `C:` drive.

Comment: I want this for my own use, so Firefox will be found.

Comment: @zeddex - Guideline: don't hardcode stuff if you don't have to ;)

Comment: The `Desktop` class will launch the default browser and provide an answer to point 1.  But still not .1% of what is required for an automation tool that can interact with/observe *'other programs'*.

Answer (score 3):

You're simply not going to get very much mileage from Java Runtime.exec(), IMHO...

Here's an alternative that should let you do some/most of what you're trying to do ... from Perl (not Java):

- [Programatically find page load times for top-1000 websites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6569320/programatically-find-page-load-times-for-top-1000-websites)

That's just an example.  There are many, many other alternatives.  If you want to go the Java route, search for "screen scrapers" or "automation".  For example:

- http://www.manageability.org/blog/stuff/screen-scraping-tools-written-in-java/view
- http://code.google.com/p/selenium/

'Hope that helps

Comment: Perl would be good if i was using that but this needs to be Java because that is the programming language i was using. I am making a automation tool but want to learn to do this myself rather than use a library which is why i asked. Thanks for the reply though.

Comment: @zeddex - To paraphase Yoda: "Do or do not... there is no Runtime.exec()" ;)

Comment: @zeddex - Guideline: don't reinvent the wheel if you don't have to.  Not only do you "get the job done", but you get a chance to learn from a successful design - and maybe invent something better!

Comment: Getting back what seems to be fairly standard response information from exec is not exactly reinventing the wheel though. There is probably ways to use a while loop and program check to test if the program is running but i was thinking there would be a solution built in to java for this since it can start the programs.

Comment: If i were to use selenium or another library though, how can it get all of the data i requested in my original question. Do you know or have links to the java code which can do that if possible? thanks

Comment: *"making a automation tool"*  Java is the ***wrong*** language.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to take a look at Selenium...
Basically, you need (of course) a monitor for the firefox process, and since Firefox does not offer COM you need sth "inside" firefox, i.e. a plugin. This is what selenium does. Such a plugin then could send you any internals for instance through a simple tcp connection.